# Password-restricting access to any application on an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, security

Ok I have a iPhone and I would like to know if there a way to restrict access, via a password, to any application installed on the device?

For example: if I wanted to access a specific game or the Contacts application I would need to enter a password beyond what I had to enter to unlock the phone itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantly, at the moment, that can't happen with an unmodified device. However, if you are jailbroken, [here's a list](http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-password-protect-apps-on-iphone-ipad/) of jailbreak tweaks that could work (most are not free sadly):

- Lockdown pro: comes in lite versions and pro versions. Pro version comes with SBSettings toggle and is $4.99 ($2.99 on iPad)
- iProtect: Free trial, becomes $8.99 after trial ends
- AppLocker: $0.99
- FolderLock: $1.59

Answer (score 0):

Parental Controls found in Settings > General > Restrictions is what I think you are looking for. 
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4213?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US